# Addhandler different from += handler syntax

Tags: c#, ironpython, routed-events

The question has been asked for c# similar: [Is using AddHandler functionally different from Event += Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735613/is-using-addhandler-functionally-different-from-event-method)

but my research gave different results opposed to the answer that has been given there.

I wrote a litte demo in IronPython based on http://manaspatnaik.com/blog/index.php/technology/wpf/routed-event-in-wpf-introduction/244

Here is the code:

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window
from System.Windows.Media import Brushes
from System.Windows import EventManager
from System.Windows import RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfTestApplication1.xaml')

        #self.MyPanel.MouseMove += self.Mouse_Move_Handler

        delegate = RoutedEventHandler(self.Mouse_Move_Handler)
        self.routed_events = EventManager.GetRoutedEvents()
        mouse_move_event = [ev for ev in self.routed_events if ev.Name =='MouseMove'][0]
        self.MyPanel.AddHandler(mouse_move_event,delegate)

        self.MyPanel.MouseLeave += self.Mouse_Leave_Handler
        self.MyButton.MouseMove += self.Button_Handler
        self.MyButton.Click += self.Button_Click
        self.MyButton.Click += self.Button_Click

    def Mouse_Move_Handler(self, sender, e):
        self.MyPanel.Background = Brushes.Red
        self.MyLabel.Content = 'Inside Panel'

    def Mouse_Leave_Handler(self,sender,e):
        self.MyPanel.Background = Brushes.Cyan
        self.MyLabel.Content = 'Outside Panel'

    def Button_Handler(self, sender, e):
        self.MyPanel.Background = Brushes.DarkBlue
        e.Handled = True

    def Button_Click(self, sender, event):
        self.MyLabel.Background = Brushes.SaddleBrown

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MyWindow()
    Application().Run(win)
```

Now the behavior seems to be exactly the same. Is there a reason for the AddHandler routine?
Also one might take into account that trying to do:

```
 AddHandler(self.MouseMove,delegate) or AddHandler(Window.MouseMove,delegate)
```

leads to the error:

```
ArgumentTypeException was unhandled by user code
expected RoutedEvent, got BoundEvent
```

Can anyone clarify the situation? Where is the difference?

EDIT: By using Control.MouseMoveEvent instead of mouse_move_event was extracted form EventManager the Code can be reduced by these two lines:

```
    #self.routed_events = EventManager.GetRoutedEvents()
    #mouse_move_event = [ev for ev in self.routed_events if ev.Name =='MouseMove'][0]
```

I can't really see any difference.